# Curves in a non-normal surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

We are studying the behavior of families of curves inside stable families of surfaces. The non-existance of the following configurations of curves in a non-normal surface would be sufficient to prove our result.

Let $X$ be a non-normal surface over $\mathbb{C}$ with non-normal locus (i.e. double locus) $X_{dl}$.

Let $D \subset X$ be a nodal curve, with node $p$ so that $p \subset X_{dl}$, the pair $(X,D)$ has semi-log canonical singularities, and $K_X + D$ is ample.

Let $C = C_g \cup C_0$ be a genus $g(C) = g$ reducible curve, which is the union of a genus $g$ curve $C_g$ and a rational curve $C_0$. Further suppose that $C_g \cap C_0 = p$ (the node of $D$), and that $C_0 \subseteq X_{dl}$.

Finally, suppose that $C_0 \cap D = p$, the normalization of $X$ is irreducible, and the preimage of $X_{dl}$ under the normalization is irreducible.

Is such a configuration possible? For instance, is $C_0 \cap D$ forced to be more than one point?

**edit**: already the case $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ is non-trivial for us.